# Flash Fullscreen onLoad?

Tags: flash, fullscreen, onload

Does someone know how I can get a Flash Movie fullscreen onLoad?

Thanks!

Best.

Answer (score 2):

In a browser this is not possible. Any move to fullscreen mode must be performed via a user interaction such as a keypress or mouse click.