# Fullscreen Flash Mode

Tags: flash

there is a flash application which has a "Fullscreen" functionality. That simply means that there is a link within the flash application called "Fullscreen". And when you click on the "Fullscreen" link a fullscreen mode appears.

Here is the flash application:
http://issuu.com/qslibrary/docs/qs-mba-career-guide-spring-2010?documentId=100428145108-725c3082ecc1401e89893c1d25d71182

Now what I want is to directly go into the "Fullscreen" flash mode by clicking on a html link (without loading the flash application before and clicking within the flash application).

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this was possible (and I'm pretty sure it isn't: [Flash Fullscreen onLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170611/flash-fullscreen-onload) ), you shouldn't do it.

When your content goes into full screen without the user requesting full screen mode, you are essentially taking over their computer. User's may not understand that they are still inside of the browser and may not know how to exit full screen mode.

The best approach would simply be to suggest that the user try using full screen mode. (And make sure there is a button to easily exit full screen mode.)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash runs inside a sandbox exactly for this reason. If every Flash advert had the ability to make itself fullscreen without you clicking a button on it first, people would go insane! The only kind of way round this is by using Javascript to make the browser window fullscreen, but this isn't advised.

I just suggest trying a big 'Click Me!' button, it wouldn't hurt the user too much.